# Android:How to convert a specific Row in SQLite Database to a file like html or docx or pdf?

Tags: android, html, sqlite, file, row

I am woking on an Applicaion which takes Input it form of text and Images and stores it into Database. Considering a program which have two images in input and two text fields. How can i then pull out just one entire specific Row from the database and convert it Into some file like .docx or .pdf or more preferable a .html form.

I've tried to do that but only was able to create a text file using the BufferedWriter methods which had all the text fields from the database but I want images too.

Please if someone have the solution to my answer please provide a code to with clear explanation.I m more than just a beginner, more close to a category called Noob. Please help me out with that.

Comment: Share whatever u tried  ... and for above Problem u need to clear a static template then put your data and save with Html Extension

Comment: public void saveFile()
    {
        s1 = e1.getText().toString();
        fx=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"//localfile/"+s1+".txt");

        b0 = fx.exists();

        if(!fx.exists())
        {
            try{
                fx.createNewFile();
                FileWriter nx = new FileWriter(fx.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(nx);
                bw.write(s1);
                bw.close();
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {


            }

        }
Abv code generates text file

Comment: http://karanbalkar.com/2013/05/tutorial-22-generate-pdf-using-droidtext-in-android/      try this

Comment: In my example i just tried to pull out text, because i've no idea about how to deal with Images. Will this help me work with images too?

Comment: Well seems like karabalkar's droidtext library is not available for download.. or even for free use. Any other method??